# Undo colour Blending in Pygame

Tags: python-3.x, colors, pygame

In a game that I'm working on using pygame, I'm trying add hitflash. To those who are unfamiliar with what this is, hitflash is an effect where an enemy flashes a colour - usually white - for about half a second (Don't quote me on that, that's my way of describing it). This can be done with the `Surface.fill()` function by passing in an additional argument. In order to achieve the hitflash effect, I fill the image with white and blend it. However, I am unaware of how I can revert the image to how it was before it was blended with white. I can easily create duplicates of the original images and load the original ones that weren't blended, but I find that this is too inefficient with what I'm working with. Is there a way/function that allows for blending to be undone (i.e, change blended image back to normal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fill`ing a surface will modify it, so I recommend swapping the image for a brighter version when the object takes damage. Create the bright version before the while loop or load another version of the image and then swap it by assigning the current image to another variable.

You probably also need a timer to control how fast the image will be reset to the original version.

I suggest that you do that in your sprite classes not in the while loop as in the minimal example below.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
image_normal = pg.Surface((30, 50))
image_normal.fill(pg.Color('dodgerblue'))
image_bright = image_normal.copy()
image_bright.fill((100, 100, 100, 0), special_flags=pg.BLEND_RGBA_ADD)
image = image_normal  # The currently selected image.
timer = 0
dt = 0

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            image = image_bright  # Swap the image.
            timer = .5  # 0.5 seconds.

    timer -= dt
    if timer <= 0:
        image = image_normal  # Set the image back to the normal version.
        timer = 0

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    screen.blit(image, (300, 200))
    pg.display.flip()
    dt = clock.tick(60) / 1000

pg.quit()
```

Comment: So there is no way to just change the surface back to normal at all? Also, when using special flags with blitting, is the image blended with the surface it is blitted on?

Comment: No, you could try to add 50 to a color channel with `BLEND_RGBA_ADD` and subtract 50 with `BLEND_RGBA_SUB` to revert it. However, imagine what happens when you add 50 to 230 and then subtract it again. You'd get 205 instead of 230 because the values of the color channels are clamped between 0 and 255.

Comment: *"Also, when using special flags with blitting, is the image blended with the surface it is blitted on?"* -- Yes, check out this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_mode) to learn what the blend modes do.

Comment: When I try subtracting 255,255,255 from 255,255,255, I'm left with black instead of white. Why doesn't the image revert to normal then?

Comment: 255 - 255 = 0 and (0, 0, 0) is black.

Comment: I came to that realization and facepalmed unimaginably hard

Comment: Hehe, don't worry, that can happen to anyone. ;)